# Why do so many newspapers use the word "Times" in their names?

Tags: history, names

It seems that the word itself doesn't mean news or newspapers, but many newspapers use it in their names. Is there a historic reason?

Comment: "It seems that the word itself doesn't mean news" -- Seems to whom? "The times they are a-changin'" -- Bob Dylan.

Comment: @Jim: *times* doesn't mean *news*; you wouldn't say *the news are changing*

Comment: To state the obvious, the word "times" RELATES to the subject that newspapers deal with, which answers the question of why the word is in the name of a number of newspapers. That "times" is not an exact synonym for "news" is obviously beside the point.

Comment: @F'x Not an intellectually honest argument, since I *would* say "the news it is a-changin'".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The name originally comes from the British newspaper *The Daily Universal Register* founded in 1785, which changed it names to *The Times* in 1788. Since then it has lent its name to papers all over the world.

[Wikipedia: The Times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times)

The original meaning of *time* is *to happen*, so *the times* means *that what has happened*, which is a fitting name for a newspaper.

[Online Etymology Dictionary: time (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=time)

Comment: "The original meaning of _time_ is _to happen_" -- where does this come from?  The _dictionary.com_ entry for _time_ does not show any such thing (and BTW, the actual link above goes somewhere else).

Comment: @mgkrebbs: Sorry, I pasted the wrong link. I believe that the dictionary.com page did contain that information, but has switched sources... I found it elsewhere and updated the link.

Comment: The original meaning of the English **verb** _time_ is ‘to happen’. The original meaning of the **word** _time_ is… ‘time’. That’s what the noun (which is much older than the verb) has meant since long before there was any such thing as English.

Answer (score 4):

Simple: Currency, and location in history, as in "these are *the Times* that try mens' souls." You want yesterday's news?

There are also plenty of Heralds, Bugles, and even some "Cryers" (as in "Town-"), for the obvious reason that they are "announcing" the latest doings.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt about English, I like to go back to my Dutch roots.

The Dutch words for 'newspaper' is '[krant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/krant)', which derives from the Dutch word '[courant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/courant#Dutch)'.

The Dutch word 'courant' can mean either newspaper or currency (money), and it derives from the French '[courant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/courant#French)', which, when used as an adjective, means current or present (time).  Another English term that derives directly from the French is '[au courant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_courant)', which means, literally, up to date, informed on the latest developments etc.

This leads back to the idea of a newspaper reporting what is happening at the *current time*.

Along with newspapers that use the word 'Times' in their name, you will also find many that use 'Courant'.